# Is it possible to add custom filters/logic on messages with Quickblox Messages API

Tags: quickblox

We are considering using Quickblox for a chat app. However, we have some business logic that should be integrated with the message on the server side.

For instance, when a message is received on the server and contains some particular text, we have to run some functions (to filter crude content for instance). We also have a billing system which should account who sent what/when, etc.

Is it possible to do that with Quickblox ?

Best regards

Flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At now, no way to integrate some server logic via QB admin panel.  This feature will soon appear. 
You should create your logic on client side.